# Make text boxes in a row required if any other text box of a row is filled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, conditional-statements

I am posting my `FormCollection` to my `HttpPost` Action in `Asp.Net MVC`. Everything is working fine but the problem is validation. I have 3 Rows each with 3 textboxes. I want to make sure through `JavaScript` or `C#` that if any `textbox` of a row is filled then others are required. I cannot make it static since rows and textboxes are very dynamic. We could have five rows, six or many.
Following is my code:

```
@{
     int count = 0;
     foreach (var record in Model)
     {
       <tr>
         <td> 
            @Html.Hidden(count.ToString() + "Record", record.Id.ToString())
         </td>
         <td>
                <input type="text" name="@count.ToString()Code" />         
         </td>
         <td>
                <input type="text" name="@count.ToString()Name" />     
         </td>           
       </tr>
       count = count + 1;
     }
     @Html.Hidden("TotalRecords", count)
}
```

Suppose, I have three rows each with code and name. If the code of `row1` is filled, I need to make sure the name of 'row1' should be filled to. How can I do this?

Comment: Create a view model with properties `Code` and `Name`. Apply a conditional validation attribute. e.g. a [foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIfNotEmpty("Code")` to your `Name` property. Then generate your view correctly by passing a collection of your model to the view and strongly bind to it using the `HtmlHelper` methods (including `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` so you get client and server side validation and you can bind to you model in the POST method

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by adding class to all your textboxes. Verify that if textbox with that class has no value then display message as shown in below code

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
var Flag=0;
debugger
$('.textBox').each(function(i) {
   if($(this).val()=="")
   {
   if(Flag==0)
   {
   Flag=1+i;
}
}

});

if(Flag!=0)
{
alert("Please fill textbox : "+Flag)
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="textBox" > <br />
<input type="text" class="textBox" > <br />
<input type="text" class="textBox" > <br />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" >
```